# have a prob.I already click the second textbox but it keeps appearing in both. I WANT THE NUMBER TO POP WHEN I CLICK ITS TEXTBOX. 1 at the time

Tags: c#

MY CODE:

namespace textbox
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "2";


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        textBox1.Text = textBox2.Text += "1";

    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your `button1_Click` method, the `textBox1.Text` is attributed the result of concatenating "1" to `textBox2.Text`. I think this is the cause of your problem.